# How to run a query for "Today's" date from 12:00am to 11:59PM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple query that pulls a payout report for our day.  I'd like to automate this to send every night, however I want the report to run for That day 12:00AM - 11:59 PM daily...  I will be sending the reports at 9:00 PM, so I suppose it will only need to get until 9:00 PM if that's easier.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Number, SUM(dblPayoutAmt) AS Amount
FROM            Payouts
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

Comment: What is your stumbling point? you have the query right there. passing parameters?

Comment: Yea, I want the variables to go away, and just have it always run "TODAYS" date.  So for example, this will be a program that runs via windows scheduler, I want the query to pull the information for the day, and then my program will put it into a table and send it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use BETWEEN, use >= the start date and < a day past the end date:

```
WHERE (dtCreated >= @startdate AND dtCreated < DATEADD(day, 1, @enddate))
```

The reason is that BETWEEN will find up until 12:00am of the end date, but not past then.

**UPDATED**

For todays date, you can do this:

```
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dtCreated)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

This will check that it has a `dtCreated` equal to some point today.

**UPDATED**

As @ScottChapman has pointed out, you can do the same thing without the conversion gymnastics by casting to the `DATE` type directly.  This type is only available in MSSQL 2008 and later, however.

Comment: I don't want to use variables, i'm looking to replace the '@startdate' and '@enddate'

Comment: Yes, again it will be automated, so when i run it tomorrow, I'll need tomorrows date, etc.

Comment: Where will it be getting the date from? DB side? or PC running the program?

Comment: `GETDATE()` is TSQL for 'current date and time' (from the DB server).  Wrapping it in `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))` gets the beginning of today (at 12:00am).  Wrapping `dtCreated` the same way, gets the beginning of that day.  Comparing these 2 values tells you if they occurred on the same day.  If you want to compare against the time of the PC running the program (assuming they are in a different time-zone for example), you have no choice but to pass parameters as variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @StartDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate))

SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Number, SUM(dblPayoutAmt) AS Amount
FROM            Payouts
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

Comment: You are taking 11:59 too literally methinks :)  I guess I can't fault you for giving what is asked for...

Answer (score 2):

Some of these answers are close, but exclude times in the final minute of the day, like 11:59:30 PM.  This query will include all of today:

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Number, SUM(dblPayoutAmt) AS Amount
FROM            Payouts
WHERE        (dtCreated >= CAST(GETDATE() as date) AND dtCreated < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() as date)))
```

Note that this won't work in SQL Server 2005 or below, as the `date` type was added in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using SQL/Server 2008 you can remove any time element from a DATETIME column by converting it to DATE and select on that, E.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number, SUM(dblPayoutAmt) AS Amount
  FROM Payouts
 WHERE CONVERT(DATE,dtCreated) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

Very much more elegant

[EDIT]
Oh, I've just read Scott Chapman's answer, it's better because if dtCreated is indexed then the query will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Preceding answers also include data < 12.00 am

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS Number
  , SUM(dblPayoutAmt) AS Amount
FROM 
  Payouts
WHERE
  dtCreated >= dateadd( hour, 12, cast( cast( getdate() as date ) as datetime ))
  and dtCreated < dateadd( second, -1, dateadd(day, datediff(day, -1, getdate()), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

set them both to SIMPLE date example: `BETWEEN '2012-12-19' AND '2012-12-20'` with no timestamp on them, then select the between.

In this example if you set the date for end to `'2012-12-20 23:59:59.999'` and then do a `SELECT @enddate` it returns `'2012-12-21 00:00:00.000'`

OR to use a function type syntax:

```
  declare @mystart as datetime
  declare @myend as datetime
  set @mystart = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)
  set @myend = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),1) 
  select @mystart, @myend
```

the @mystart here is set to ONLY the date part (time is 00:00:00.000) and the end is sent to that plus one day, so the BETWEEN syntax works.